# Calling mod_timer from inside timer callback function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel module for linux, and I want my timer to re-set itself. To this end, I thought to call `mod_timer` from inside the timer's callback function, as shown:

```
static void sched_send(unsigned long data)
{
    send_now();
    mod_timer(&test_timer, jiffies+(get_interval()*HZ));
}

static void timer_start(void)
{
    set_log_msg("Meep meep!");

    test_timer.function = sched_send;
    test_timer.expires = jiffies + HZ*get_interval();
}
```

However, I've read `mod_timer` deletes the timer and re-adds it. Will it cause problems? If so, is there a better way to create a repeating timer for kernel modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `timer_start()` will have to call `add_timer()` after it sets up the function and the expiration time.  Once the timer function triggers, your timer is no longer active, so all you have to do is reset the `.expires` field to your new value and call `add_timer()` again.  Be sure you provide a clean way to stop rescheduling the timer, for example on module unload.

```
send_now();
if(!terminate_timer) {
    test_timer.expires = jiffies + HZ*get_interval();
    add_timer(&test_timer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to execute `mod_timer` from the timer callback.

From the kernel source (kernel/timer.c):

```
/* mod_timer(timer, expires) is equivalent to:
*
*     del_timer(timer); timer->expires = expires; add_timer(timer);
*     ...
*/
```

As for `del_timer`,

```
/*
* del_timer - deactive a timer.
* @timer: the timer to be deactivated
*
* del_timer() deactivates a timer - this works on both active and inactive
* timers. 
* ...
*/
```

As noted by Peter, you need to invoke `add_timer` anytime you want to start/restart the timer.